# FormatException: Unexpected character (at line 2, character 13). Dart/Flutter jsonDecode

Tags: json, flutter, dart

[image]

When i `print(response.body)` it works fine

Comment: You are having invalid json data in response , You can also check for status codes

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an invalid json data in the response.

1. Paste you json from **response.data** here [json validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)
2. Do not use async functions in the **initState** method

Use [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html) method

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
 await getData();
}
```